# Cannot Import scipy in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I run two line code, can you let me know what is the issue in importing the scipy in jupyter notebook
Python Version is 3.7.7

### ! pip install scipy

Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.4.1)

### Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from scipy) (1.18.2)

### import scipy

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import scipy

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy__init__.py in 
    154     # This makes "from scipy import fft" return scipy.fft, not np.fft
    155     del fft
--> 156     from . import fft

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\fft__init__.py in 
     74 from **future** import division, print_function, absolute_import
     75 
---> 76 from ._basic import (
     77     fft, ifft, fft2, ifft2, fftn, ifftn,
     78     rfft, irfft, rfft2, irfft2, rfftn, irfftn,

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\fft_basic.py in 
----> 1 from scipy._lib.uarray import generate_multimethod, Dispatchable
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
      4 
      5 def _x_replacer(args, kwargs, dispatchables):

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy_lib\uarray.py in 
     25     from uarray import _Function
     26 else:
---> 27     from ._uarray import *
     28     from ._uarray import _Function
     29

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy_lib_uarray__init__.py in 
    112 """
    113 
--> 114 from ._backend import *
    115 
    116 **version** = '0.5.1+5.ga864a57.scipy'

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy_lib_uarray_backend.py in 
     13 import inspect
     14 import functools
---> 15 from . import _uarray  # type: ignore
     16 import copyreg  # type: ignore
     17 import atexit

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

check to see if you are pip installing it with the right version and distribution of python that Jupiter is using.

Visual Studio Code, Anaconda/Jupyter, etc sometimes has their own installation of python that is not the one you might have downloaded at some point from the python website.

If you are using pip to install things, pip might be installed for another version you are using and adding it to the package list of another python installation.